# How do I remove a trailing slash of subdomain URL in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, trailing-slash

Currently, when a request is made for a URL that is not a directory, my .htaccess is set up to remove any trailing slash. The problem is, that is causing test.domain.com/order.php/ to be redirected to test.domain.com/test/order.php instead of test.domain.com/order.php. It works perfectly when not in a subdomain.

Here is the .htaccess code I am using to remove trailing slashes:

```
    #if it's not a directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #and it has a trailing slash, then redirect to URL without slash
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Somehow, the subdirectory the subdomain serves from is being added to the URL in addition to the subdomain already there. How can I remove the trailing slash without adding /test?

Edit:

Here is the full .htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Are there more rules in this file or this is the only one?

Comment: Added full htaccess content to post

Comment: If this is in DocumentRoot of parent domain it won't execute for subb domain (unless subdomain is not setup right). Can you show VirtualHost entry of sub domain?

Comment: I don't believe I have access to that—the site is on a shared server. However, based on your answer, I put the rule in the htaccess file of the subdirectory, and it now works as intended. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing anubhava's comment under my question, I decided to put the remove trailing slash rule in an .htaccess file in the subdomain's subdirectory. I also prevent the rule in the document root .htaccess from affecting the subdirectory (since it has its own rule):

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

It now works as intended for the main site, as well as the subdomain.